# How to specify Gateway in Contiki Cooja?

Tags: contiki

I want to simulate simple smart home iot communication with gateway in cooja.
It means that some sensor nodes communicate with a client(e.g. mobile phone) via gateway. As shown in the picture.

But I don't know how to specify the gateway.
Is the gateway, Visual, like motes? Or I should add it by code(a .c file)?
I don't have real motes and I want to simulate everything.

[image: gateway scenario]

Comment: Look into Border Router.

Comment: Thanks @kfx .I used RPL-Border-Router example in cooja. But whats the different between border router and gateway? I want to implement my authentication algorithm on gateway. Is it possible on border router?

Answer (score 2):

We usually refer to the gateway in RPL as the border router. [Here](http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/RPL_Border_Router) is an example from the Autonomous Networks Research Group of the University of Southern California on how to simulate a border router with Cooja.

> Border routers are routers that can be found at the edge of a network. Their function is to connect one network to another.

The page also links to [this guide](http://cnds.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/iotlab-2013/cooja.pdf), which explains the setup of a border router:

> The RPL border router is used in order to interface a regular IP network
>   with an RPL 6LoWPAN network. This is similar to the bridge that was previously
>   used, except that it also runs an RPL network. The border router is
>   located in the `contiki-2.6/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router`folder. You
>   must compile it using the following commands:
>
> ```
> cd contiki -2.6/ examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router
> make TARGET=sky
> ```

(the directory referred to is available [here, on GitHub](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router))

They also specify how to select mote types in section 3.4, including the border router.

Comment: Welcome! I edited your post to include some of the referenced material, since, as @anonymous2 mentions, link-only answers are discouraged. You might like to check that you're happy with the edits, and choose any further relevant material to include here. Thanks.